# Sorting dictionary values and getting sorted keys in new dictionary using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sorting, dictionary, values

How can I sort a dictionary's keys in Earth Engine based on their values?

For example, I have such a dictionary defined in Earth Engine after some calculations and I want to sort that based on dictionary values and get sorted new dictionary based on sorted keys and values.

Here is a simple example for that :

```
var MyDic=ee.Dictionary({
  A: 2.318244235030834,
  B: 8.901825525058984,
  C: 6.9262150730973815,
  D: 1.1614314188052866
})
print('MyDic',MyDic)
var Sorted=ee.Dictionary(MyDic).values().sort()

print('Sorted',Sorted)

var sorted_new_keys = Sorted.map(function(ele) {
  
  return MyDic.get(ele);
  
});

print('sorted_new_keys',sorted_new_keys)
//
```

So I could see the values as (8.90, 6.93 and so on).

When I run the above code I receive the following results:

```
Sorted
List (4 elements)
0: 1.1614314188052866
1: 2.318244235030834
2: 6.9262150730973815
3: 8.901825525058984
```

I want to get true keys as A, B, ... not 0, 1, ...

My full code is at https://code.earthengine.google.com/b42a11a87457daef9eb9b8b256f461c2

Comment: `ee.Dictionary`? or javascript object?

Comment: Also, if an answer solves your question, you can hit the checkmark next to the answer to accept it. This let's other users know that the question is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because dictionaries by design do not have an order, you can't really sort a dictionary itself, only the keys or the values. If you want the order of the keys, based on some sort of other values, you could simply use the `keys` argument of `ee.List.sort()`.

```
var dict = ee.Dictionary({
  A: 2.318244235030834,
  B: 8.901825525058984,
  C: 6.9262150730973815,
  D: 1.1614314188052866
})

var sorted_keys = dict.keys().sort(dict.values())
```

This sorts the keys of the dictionary based on the order of the values. But since dictionaries do not have an intrinsic order, you have to save everything as a List, or as list of lists.

```
var sorted = ee.List([sorted_keys, dict.values().sort()])
print(sorted)
```

Another option would be to save the keys and values as seperate properties in a feature collection and sort that.

```
var dict_to_fc = ee.FeatureCollection(dict.keys().map(function(k){
  return ee.Feature(null, {key: k, value: dict.getNumber(k)})
}))

var sorted = dict_to_fc.sort('value')
print(sorted)
```