# Creating table from lists in sorted manner in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, csv, table, sorting

I have calculated the area coverage of landcover types in a region and sort them
now I want to export the results as a table to drive in a sorted manner

when I combine them in a new dictionary object type their sort is not applied and I obtain an unsorted values

thus I want to export them as a table to drive in a sorted manner

How can I do that?

In detail I have two lists for an example lists (for shorter representation):

```
var b=ee.List([4.5,2.8,7.4])
var c= ee.List(['a','b','c'])
print('b',b)
var dict=ee.Dictionary.fromLists(c,b)
print('dict',dict)

var ssf=b.sort()
print('ssf',ssf)
var getindex = function(x) {
  return ssf.indexOf(x);
};
var valsb = b.map(getindex);
print('valsb',valsb)



var getval = function(x) {
  return dict.values().get(x);
};
var xz=ee.List(valsb)
var vals = xz.map(getval);
print('vals',vals)

var tt=[valsb,vals]
print('tt',tt)
```

but I want to have this table or list to export as txt or csv

```
0: b;2.8
1: a;4.5
2: c;7.4
```

here is the code

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2FSolmaz%2FBurdur_Sentinel_CloudFree%3ACallDictValues_Test

Comment: Use Feature Collections. See the second part of this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/415823/157379

Comment: so thanks that's good and well work. but i want to export data as a simple table one column representing labels (b,a,c) and the second column consisting of percentage values as (2.8,4.5,7.4). is there any yway to generate such a table and export that to table?

Comment: If you tried it you would know that this is exactly what you get when exporting the feature collection.

Comment: i run that of course but result is not as i need. i need just a table not a feature collection that i should get access to its element by clicking on 'features'--> 'Feature 3'-->'properties'  repeteadly to access the data. i nead a siple presentation to export to drive as txt or csv file. looks like as mentioned above. by the way thanks my freind

Comment: You can export a feature collection as csv. It will be how you need it.

Answer (score 0):

By the help of dear JonasV, I could complete the code as I need. Here is the full code:

```
var b=ee.List([4.5,2.8,7.4])
var c= ee.List(['a','b','c'])
print('b',b)
var dict=ee.Dictionary.fromLists(c,b)
print('dict',dict)


var sorted_keys = dict.keys().sort(dict.values())
print(sorted_keys)

var sorted = ee.List([sorted_keys, dict.values().sort()])
print('sorted',sorted)

var dict_to_fc = ee.FeatureCollection(dict.keys().map(function(k){
  return ee.Feature(null, {key: k, value: dict.getNumber(k)})
}))

var sorted = dict_to_fc.sort('value')
print(sorted)


Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: sorted,
  description:'SolmazCSV',
  fileFormat: 'csv'
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2FSolmaz%2FBurdur_Sentinel_CloudFree%3ASolved_Sort_Dictionary